# Postfix, make "Connect from" and "Disconnect from" message to not appear in the log

Tags: postfix

How can I configure postfix for it will NOT log "Connect from" and "Disconnect from" events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. But if you use e.g. syslog-ng, you can filter logged messages there.
See here: https://www.balabit.com/sites/default/files/documents/syslog-ng-ose-latest-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-guide-admin/html/configuring-filters.html

Comment: The messages "Connect from" and "Disconnect from" can't be suppressed because they are hardcoded [here](https://github.com/vdukhovni/postfix/blob/master/postfix/src/smtpd/smtpd.c#L5295) and [here](https://github.com/vdukhovni/postfix/blob/master/postfix/src/smtpd/smtpd.c#L5333).

Comment: Wow )) it really most exhaustive answer! Thank you )